# MySQL updating email addresses and assigning them ip's

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on a project which will sell a product to a user, and on checkout completion, the user will enter an email address. I have been trying (but to no avail so far) to use MySQL to put this data into a database. Only in a certain way. I need the input data to use the UPDATE method to be put into an already existing row. This row should match the following criteria. It should not have already been used, the email should not already exist within the database. I have tried so many different pieces of MySQL, I get all sorts from syntax errors to it updating every record in my table, I have gotten as far as it updating just one, but not checking if it already exists. I was hoping for a little insight as to how I can improve!
Code as follows:

```js
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Josh";
$password = "10584066";
$dbname = "customers";
// Get email address from input form
$Email = $_GET['keyword'];
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "UPDATE list SET Email='$Email' , In_Use='1' WHERE In_Use='0' LIMIT 1";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
 header('Location: /liteservers/logon/wood.php'); 
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

So, as you can see. The code is working almost as intended, I just want it to also check to see IF the email is already in the database and if it is, perhaps add the time that it attempted to record a new email within the same row as the already found existing email. I hope this actually makes sense if you need any more info that I haven't provided, let me know!

Comment: Suggestion: Try to first model your stuff with SQL, then translate this to PHP. Also, since you say "my code doesn't work", you will need to provide a [mcve], which should be in SQL, unless of course the integration with PHP is what gives you problems.

Comment: One more thing: Do not create SQL queries in PHP yourself! If `$Email` contained the string `'; drop table list;` or some similar SQL Injection (make sure you know what this term means!) you could easily be screwed by a malicious user. Instead, use PDO for that.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: So if you want to be sure the email has not been used before, you will have to run a query to select or count all occurances of this email in the table before deciding to update this user with this email

Comment: Thank you, i am aware of the dangers of slq injection and all, this site is not live as of yet, i'm just trying to sort out the core functionality first :) I am very new to php and mysql also so thanks for being patient :)

Comment: My current code now looks like this: https://pastebin.com/k63SpTC2

Comment: I am getting a non defined variable error on $sql but i hope i'm on the right track with trying to see if the email is already in use

Answer (score 0):

Use [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax and [mysql_affected_rows](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) will tell you if its and insert or update.